# Modifying the AJAX Control Toolkit Dropdown extender

Tags: asp.net, asp.net-ajax, ajaxcontroltoolkit

I am using the example on the AJAX website for the [`DropDownExtender`](http://www.asp.net/ajaxLibrary/AjaxControlToolkitSampleSite/DropDown/DropDown.aspx).  I'm looking to make the target control (the label) have the DropDown image appear always, instead of just when I hover over it.

Is there any way to do this?

Comment: You might want to provide a link to the website you're referring to; I can't tell what example you're talking about.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This can be done using the following script tag:

```
<script>
    function pageLoad()
    {
        $find('TextBox1_DropDownExtender')._dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover();
        $find('TextBox1_DropDownExtender').unhover = VisibleMe;
    }  

    function VisibleMe()
    {
        $find('TextBox1_DropDownExtender')._dropWrapperHoverBehavior_onhover();
    }
</script>
```

I found this and some other tips at [this dot net curry example](http://www.dotnetcurry.com/ShowArticle.aspx?ID=167).

It works but I'd also consider writing a new control based on the drop down extender exposing a property to set the behaviour you want on or off.

Writing a new AJAX control isn't too hard, more fiddly than anything.